# Given the choice of using replace with regex/backreferences or split/replace, which would you choose?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I want to grab the relevant parts of a URI's query string, I've got the choice of using either of these two methods, both of which work. It might not be worth obsessing over, but given the choice, which of these methods would you pick, and why?

A)

```
var PN = this.href.replace(/.*&partNum=(.*)&partName=.*/, '$1');
var PName = this.href.replace(/.*&partName=(.*)&class=.*/, '$1');
```

B)

```
var hrefSplit = this.href.split('&');
var PN = hrefSplit[1].replace('partNum=', '');      
var PName = hrefSplit[2].replace('partName=', '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I'd use either of them, they both rely too much on the format of the query string. (Consider what happens if the query string has `partName` *before* `partNum`.) That sort of thing is usually a maintenance hassle waiting to happen.

Instead, I'd convert the query string into a map (using a centralized function for the purpose) and then retrieve the relevant parts of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Both are hazardous according to parameter order, you should parse like this:

```
var num = url.match(/\WpartNum=(\w*)/)[1];
var name = url.match(/\WpartName=(\w*)/)[1];
```

or

```
var pNum = /\WpartNum=(\w*)/.exec(url)[1];
var pName = /\WpartName=(\w*)/.exec(url)[1];
```

Comment: Probably want some delimiter on the fronts of those, otherwise "foopartNum" messes them up. Also thinking `\w` is a bit limiting. `[^&=]`, perhaps.

Comment: @t-j-crowder Yes I'm fixing it with a `\W`.